# Collapse all #regions only(!) in C# (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-editor

There's a number of keyboard shortcuts and menu commands to automatically expand or collapse all foldables in the current document. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> toggles all foldables recursively, from the top namespace down to the inner methods and comments. Basically everything that has a [+] icon in the left margin. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> does it bit less, but it still touches methods and comments inside the class.

I'm looking for a function that specifically **only** regards `#region` foldables and nothing else. Not namespaces, classes, comments, or methods. I really only want to fold those areas that are explicitly marked as such with the `#region` keyword.

Is there any hidden shortcut or an extension for that?

I'd prefer a keyboard solution, for Visual Studio 2015 (RC for now).

In case somebody asks why: I want to get an overview of the file, but immediately see all the details when I decide to look inside one region.

Comment: I don't think so (open to correction though). Have you tried class view - it will show all the class members (not the drop down at the top of the text editor) and you can double click to jump to the selected member.

Comment: I think there is no such thing, Ctrl+M,Ctrl+O is the closest

Comment: The Class View window contains the items all in one flat list, not "regioned" at all. That's not what I am using regions for. I need regions to quickly find members by topic, especially in long classes with a small number of similar methods each for a different model type. Regions group them by model type here.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Visual Studio extension [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) from Microsoft has a feature called Quick Launch Tasks that adds new commands to the Quick Launch menu. One of them is **CollapseRegions** and it does exactly that.

The opposite command is **ExpandRegions** and it expands all regions for quick browsing of the entire file. These commands can be used pretty quickly by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> hotkey and typing `Coll` resp. `Exp`, then pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (supposed you don't have other commands with the same prefix).

Comment: Here is the corresponding extension for Visual Studio 2017: [Quick Launch Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.QuickLaunchTasks)

Comment: No longer valid with Visual Studio 2019 because they changed the way Quick Tasks search works.

Answer (score 278):

in Visual Studio 2017 I have to activate *'Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions'* in

`Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced`

explicitly to collapse all when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Comment: Unfortunately this also collapses everything else (almost), not just regions. So this is not what I'm looking for. The Quick Launch Tasks extension still exists for VS 2017 and can be installed separately now, see me other comment.

Comment: This might not be what the OP asked for, but it's what I was looking for.

Comment: The option in the current build is "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions" and it's located in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced.  This is what I was looking for as well.  This makes Ctrl+M+O work like it did in VS 2015

Comment: Thank you! Just couldn't recall how to do this after I changed my laptop, and the exported settings seemed to misbehave. This answer saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 84):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will collapse all.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will expand all. (in VS 2013 - Toggle All outlining)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will expand all and disable outlining.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will collapse/expand the current section.

These options are also in the context menu under Outlining.

Right click in editor -> Outlining to find all options. (After disabling outlining, use same steps to enable outlinging.)

Comment: This is really the only correct answer... CTRL+ (M then O/L) will expand/collapse only the regions on a page which directly answers the original question.

Comment: Not true anymore with VS2017RC. Collasping all doesn't collapse regions. (At least the current build: 15.0.2620.0)

Comment: For VS 2017, see the answer from @Myz below.

Comment: CTRL+M+M also collapses/expands a selection (not only current section).

Answer (score 51):

To collapse regions : Tools > Options > Text Editors > C# > Advanced > 
Check "Collapse #regions when collapsing to definitions"

[image: Collapse #regions image]

Comment: Oh, we already had that one 3 years ago. See the top-most answer.

Answer (score 39):

Update for VS2022: https://github.com/mdmower/CollapseRegionExtension/releases/tag/v1.5 (thanks @ygoe)

Alternate marketplace download (same extension different author):
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CMPhys.ToggleRegions2022 (thanks @Memphis)

---

I know this is an old question, but here's an update for visual studio 2019:

The Quick Tasks solution from @ygoe's answer does not work for Visual Studio 2019, because that version changed the way the Quick Task bar searches. Plus it was never the preferred solution to the original question, since you needed to type a quick action instead of having a keyboard shortcut.

I found a different solution on the marketplace which does exactly the collapsing and expanding of all regions in the currently opened file with keyboard shortcuts: [Collapse Region](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VladH.CollapseRegionExtension)

From the extension page:

> Default key bindings are (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+Num+) and (Ctrl+R, Ctrl+Num-).
> Can be changed in Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for this great info! Since I'm not using quick tasks for much else, I might just switch to that extension. Tested and works (in VS 2017 and 2019).

Comment: Currently the update for VS 2022 is available here: https://github.com/mdmower/CollapseRegionExtension

Comment: Yep, I've been using Collapse Region for a while and started missing it now that I switched to VS2022. The original may be abandoned, however Matt Mower brought it back to life (thanks Matt!) and he also released it on the Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/CMPhys

Answer (score 25):

tick the Checkmark in Settings -> TextEditor -> C# -> Advanced -> (section Outlining) Collapse #regions when collapsing definitions.

then  right click in the editor > outlining > collapse to definitions

Answer (score 14):

I dont know if this is new, but there is a setting for the c# text edior:

Settings -> TextEditor -> C# -> Advanced -> Collapse #regions when collapsing definitions.

When its set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> will collapse the #regions.

Answer (score 8):

Looks like the closest thing is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Which will collapse the current region you are in, while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> will expand the current region you are in.

List of default keyboard shortcuts:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using the free Visual Studio extension "Menees VS Tools Extension for Visual Studio."  Just search for it in Tools --> Extensions and Updates in Visual Studio.  Once installed you just have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and just the regions will be collapsed.  Here is their website https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BillMenees.MeneesVSTools2013

To edit the settings look under Tools --> Options --> Menees VS Tools --> General.

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2022, here is the tool that works well:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=EngineDesigns.CollapseAllRegions

CTRL-M CTRL-R

to collapse all #region groups.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30350171)

Comment: Agreed with you. This question posed by OP - which I provided the answer, as I have the same issue as OP and others. I also noticed that many answers do not meet our needs.

This Engine Designs author who wrote this tool has solved the problem we are seeking - for now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about previous Visual Studio versions, but in VS 2022 we have new shortcut

`CTRL + M + M`

It will collapse any part of code like namespace, class, region etc.,

**Steps:**

1. Go to `#region` piece of code.
2. Select `#region` or click on `#region` anywhere in that word.
3. From Keyboard click  `CTRL + M + M`

If you want for entire namespace to collapse, you can do same steps by selecting or clicking `namespace`.

Comment: This has already been answered over 3 years ago and downvoted (see below). How does your answer differ from that?

Answer (score -3):

Select All via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>

*i.e.* Press <kbd>M</kbd> twice while holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, no. This collapses **everything** including namespaces, classes, methods and comments. This was explicitly not asked for.

Comment: In visual studio For javascript regions collapse Ctrl+M+O is not working but selecting all items then Ctrl+M+M is working, thanks